# Data retrieval from multiple DataSources

Tags: angular, datasource, mat

I am working on a [mat-table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#datasource) which is populated from `itemsList` using `dataSource`:

`component.ts`:

```
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<BasketItem>; 
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.itemsList);
```

`component.html`:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
</mat-table>
```

Is it possible to populate with items from a second list `itemsList2`
simultaneously?

Comment: Please clarify : should the data be merged, concatenated ... ?

Comment: no, the data allow individual processing

Comment: That doesn't make sense. I'm asking you if you want to append data to your array, or if you want to merge it into the first data fetched (or anything else but those are the two most common)

Comment: None of them. I want to be able to process in my table `dataSource: MatTableDataSource<BasketItem>; ` and another one  `dataSource: MatTableDataSource<GroupItem>;`

Comment: Okay but technically speaking that information is useless : data source is an array of object. Again, and for the last time : would you like to display new columns in your table, or would you like to create new lines in it ?

Comment: New lines  whom cells are populated with data of objects having different type(GroupItem). Thank you for your time

Comment: Okay that answers me thank you ! Now, how will one know it is different data ? Will the table headers be the same ? If not, simply use this notation `{{ el.basketId || el.groupId }}` after concatenating your arrays, and you should be good.

Comment: That's the issue, i do not have a groupId for element. They belong to a different type. I need to integrate 2 different type of objects in the table